# Preconditions of the definition of a multivariate real-valued function being real-analytic

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, analytic-functions

Recently I'm reading a text and got confused about preconditions of the definition of a multivariate real-valued function being real-analytic. Writing the coordinates on $\Bbb R^n$ as $x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ and let $p=(p^1,\dots,p^n)$ be a point in an open set $U$ in $\Bbb R^n$. Following is the definition of real-analytic of a function $f:U\to\Bbb R$ in this text:

> The function $f$ is real-analytic at $p$ if in some neighborhood of $p$ it is equal to its Taylor series
> at $p$: $$f(x)=f(p)+\sum\limits_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p)(x^i-p^i)+\frac{1}{2!}\sum\limits_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}(p)(x^i-p^i)(x^j-p^j)\\+\cdots+\frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{i_1,\dots,i_k}\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x^{i_1}\cdots\partial x^{i_k}}(p)(x^{i_1}-p^{i_1})\cdots(x^{i_k}-p^{i_k})+\cdots,$$ where the general term is summed over all $1\le i_1,\dots,i_k\le n$.

My question is, do we need to assume as preconditions in the definition of real-analytic: 1) all partial derivatives of all orders in any order exist and 2) the mixed partial derivatives are equal no matter what order with regard to which the variables are taken. As I see it, If 1) does not hold, the Taylor series would not be well-defined, not to mention it being equal to $f(x)$. If 2) is missing, I would be totally confused about what the summands in general term look like. The continuity of mixed partial derivatives can guarantee 2), but I choose not to assume these continuities to keep the list of preconditions to minimum. However, the above preconditions 1) and 2) are not mentioned explicitly in the text. I also checked the definition in some other textbooks and wikipedia, but no source states these preconditions explicitly. So I'd like to ask here for a confirmation: should we assume the above two conditions 1) and 2) in the definition of real-analytic? Two derivative questions follow: do the text and other sources just assume the above preconditions implicitly and is it a kind of convention in math community that when we write down something, all the preconditions that make sense of what is written are assumed to hold in advance and it is the reader's responsibility to figure them out? I'm self-studying so I don't have math professor or TA to ask; something that is obvious to math students may be a big obstacle for me, so I would be greatly grateful for any of your help.

Comment: I believe $f$ has to be $C^{\infty}$.
Otherwise, as you said, it is obviously not real-analytic since it has no sufficient taylor series.
This also takes care of the partial derivatives equality.

Comment: @paxtibimarce: It is true that $C^{\infty}$ implies 1) and 2), but as I said in the question, I'd like to keep preconditions to minimum, so 1) and 2) will suffice. Furthermore, a real-analytic function is necessarily $C^{\infty}$, so I think $C^{\infty}$ might be too strong for the implicit precondition. Wondering what on earth is going on in math community.

Comment: you can define a function (doesn't matter if the domain is an open subset R or R^n) to be analytic if for every point $p$ in its domain, there exists a power series (this is a concept which can be naturally defined even for several variables) with non-trivial domain of convergence such that in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of the point $p$, the function is equal to the power series. From this definition, one can prove analytic implies $C^{\infty} $ (and also deduce how the coefficients of the power series are related to the various partial derivatives).

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Does this power series have to be Taylor series? If has to, does the existence of the Taylor series implicitly imply 1) and 2) in my question?

Comment: @peek-a-boo: From the nice exchanging property of (uniformly) convergent power series, I can prove that for $f(x)$, IF there exists a power series ... (your definitive condition), then all partial derivatives exist and continuous at $p$, thus 1) and 2) hold and $f\in C^{\infty}$. So, Taylor series is well-defined and we can write it down. But a few questions follow immediately: a) Does the Taylor series converge? b) converges to $f(x)$ (this is the definition of real-analytic in my question)? c) this is an optional question: is the Taylor series the only possible power series?

Comment: Since you confirmed that the power series is equal to the Taylor series, the answers to the above three questions are a) Yes, b) Yes, and c) Yes (due to the uniqueness of power series that can be proved by nice properties of uniformly convergent power series). I'm still working on the equivalence between general power series form and Taylor series form (say, by rearrangement), but I think that should be regarded as another question. I hope I can figure it out soon. Thank you for the clarification of the definition of real-analytic functions based on existence of power series.

Comment: Work on the equivalence from power series to Taylor series is done. Thank Alex Ravsky for his help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3988381.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I'm essentially just spouting out stuff which is readily available in Henri Cartan's text on complex analysis. Let us first consider a formal power series in $n$-variables with complex coefficients,
\begin{align}
S(X_1,\dots, X_n)=\sum_{I\in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n} a_I X^I \equiv \sum_{i_1,\dots, i_n\geq 0}
a_{i_1,\dots, i_n}X_1^{i_1}\cdots X_n^{i_n}
\end{align}
So far this is just a formal series, in the sense that this is just a bunch of symbols, with no meaning attached to the sum notation. Let us now denote by $\Gamma_S$ the set of $(r_1,\dots, r_n)$ such that each $r_i\geq 0$ and such that the following sum is finite:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i_1,\dots, i_n\geq 0}|a_{i_1,\dots, i_n}|(r_1)^{i_1}\cdots (r_n)^{i_n}<\infty.
\end{align}
The set $\Gamma_S$ is of course not empty, since it contains the origin $(0,\dots, 0)$. We define the domain of convergence of $S$ to be $\Delta_S := \text{int}(\Gamma_S)$. Note that $\Delta_S$ is always an open set, but may or may not be empty. If the domain of convergence is non-empty, this means there exist $r_1,\dots, r_n>0$ such that the above sum is finite, and furthermore it is easy to show (I think it's called Weirstrass's M-test?) that if $r_1,\dots, r_n>0$ are such that the above sum is finite, then the series
\begin{align}
S(z_1,\dots, z_n)&=\sum_{i_1,\dots, i_n\geq 0}a_{i_1,\dots, i_n}(z_1)^{i_1}\cdots (z_n)^{i_n}
\end{align}

converges absolutely and uniformly whenever $|z_i|\leq r_i$ for $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ (also, you can show that if $(|z_1|,\dots, |z_n|)$ doesn't lie in the closure of $\Gamma$ then the series $S(z_1,\dots, z_n)$ diverges).

---

That was a brief intro to the basic definitions we need to talk about analyticity. Given an open set $U\subset \Bbb{R}^n$, a function $f:U\to \Bbb{R}$ is real analytic at $p$ if there exists a formal series $S$ with real coefficients, having non-empty domain of convergence $\Delta_S$, such that for $x\in U$ close to $p$ (i.e $(|x_1-p_1|,\dots, |x_n-p_n|)\in \Delta_S$), we have $f(x)= S(x_1-p_1,\dots, x_n-p_n)$.

With this, you can try to extend the usual $1$-D argument to show that if $f$ is analytic at $p$, then $f$ in some small neighbourhood of $p$, $f$ has continuous partial derivatives of all orders (so the order of differentiation doesn't matter), and that the coefficients are determined uniquely as
\begin{align}
a_{i_1,\dots, i_n}&=\frac{1}{i_1!\cdots i_n!}\frac{\partial^{i_1+\dots i_n}f}{\partial x_1^{i_1}\dots \partial x_n^{i_n}}(p)
\end{align}
Of course, since we have absolute convergence, we can rearrange the sums however we wish, so this means in a small neighbourhood of $p$, $f$ will equal its Taylor series about $p$.

Anyway, I would highly suggest you review the relevant definitions of analyticity in $1$-dimension and see what that implies about differentiability, relation to Taylor series etc, because the $n$-dimensional case simply amounts to rewording the definitions slightly and reusing the $1$-variable theorems carefully (so I hope I haven't made any typos lol).

Comment: Thank you. I understood your comment based on power series form expansion and subsequent definition of real-analytic. So I totally agree with your definition in the comment (as well as this much detailed version in the answer). What have been puzzling me since your comment (and why I remain silent since then) is how to equate the power series form with Taylor series form (by rearranging the sums mentioned in the answer, but I can't figure out how to rearrange). If this equivalence of two forms is established, I think my question would be completely solved. Thank you again for the clarification